# Reconciling Express (Passport) and AngularJS Routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am building a MEAN-stack application and am finally getting to the point of creating a user authentication. To do so, I followed this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619

Now, when I incorporate this into my project it works, but only partially. Namely, it seems that the only page I can navigate to properly is the app's home page. If I click on any links or type something other than home in the address bar, it takes me back to the login screen.

What are some possible reasons for that?

My routes/index.js file looks as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
    // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
    // request and response objects
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = function(passport){

    /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });

    /* Handle Login POST */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Registration Page */
    router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
    });

    /* Handle Registration POST */
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Home Page */
    router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('home', { user: req.user });
    });

    /* Handle Logout */
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;
}
```

I also have some AngularJS routes specified in another file (application worked perfectly with these before I started adding authentication).

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/calendar',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            //controller: 'Calendar'
        })

        .when('/add-activity', {

            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-form.html',
            controller: 'AddActivityCtrl'
        })

        .when('/activity/:id',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-form.html',
            controller: 'EditActivityCtrl'
        })

        .when('/activity/delete/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-delete.html',
            controller: 'DeleteActivityCtrl'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Is there something I am missing?

P.S. I noticed that currently my URL of home page is

> http://localhost:3000/home#/

whereas previously it was

> http://localhost:3000/#/

I added "home" to differentiate from "/" which is the authentication page; however, I am unsure about how "#" is tacked onto the path in the first quote.

Comment: I would move `var isAuthenticated` under `module.exports = function(passport){` as I am not sure if passport exists in that context. If it did not help, start commenting `res.redirect('/')`  and `redirectTo: '/'`  to understand which one is the cause.

Comment: @faster, Just to make sure I understand correctly, what should I be doing with commenting out redirects?

Comment: Just to understand which one did worked..

Comment: It seems that this piece of code is doing the redirect upon the login:

Comment: /* Handle Login POST */
 router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/home',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash : true  
 }));

Comment: When I comment out res.redirect('/') within the isAuthenticated function, nothing happens.

Comment: P.S. I moved isAuthenticated within module.exports as you suggested, but nothing seems to have changed because of that.

Comment: Well, next I would comment out `res.redirect('/');`  If that stops redirects, then you have some trouble with authentification.  Start with console.log(req)  and then check every bit you have copied from the link.

Comment: In other words, do you say that somehow the Express and AngularJS should be able to resolve the routes successfully with the code as I currently have it? 
My desire is to have Express do authentication and some RESTful stuff (I have it in another file) and have Angular do the rest. I believe it is called "one page Angular app" but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Well, it looks alright, but can't tell for sure until you run it :-)

Comment: I have tried commenting out both `res.redirect('/')` on the Express side and `redirect.to('/')` on the Angular side without any result. 
Is there a way to console.log what the actual routes are when Angular or Express are doing the routing?

Comment: I was able to fix this. See my answer below, if you are curious. Perhaps you could tell me why there is such a phenomenon.

Comment: Cool. Not yet, I still learning node :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this as follows. I changed the Express routing to contain a

> "login"

route and changed the home route to just

> "/"

As a result, the home path became

> http://localhost:3000/#/

The hash sign is tacked on by and for the Angular. From my understanding, the Angular treats such path as "/". Then, the remaining routing is done by Angular and I have a single-page AngularJS app.

Working code:
Express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport){

    var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
            // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
            // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
            // request and response objects
            if (req.isAuthenticated()){
                //console.log(next());
                return next();
            }
            // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
            res.redirect('/login');
    }


    /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('login', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });

    /* Handle Login POST */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Registration Page */
    router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
    });

    /* Handle Registration POST */
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Home Page when logged in */
    router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('index', { user: req.user });
    });

    /* GET Home Page */
    router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('index', { user: req.user });
    });

    /* Handle Logout */
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/login');
    });

    return router;
}
```

Working code: Angular

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/calendar',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            //controller: 'Calendar'
        })

        .when('/add-activity', {

            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-form.html',
            controller: 'AddActivityCtrl'
        })

        .when('/activity/:id',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-form.html',
            controller: 'EditActivityCtrl'
        })

        .when('/activity/delete/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/activity-delete.html',
            controller: 'DeleteActivityCtrl'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```